# How to delete from DB in SpringMVC

Tags: spring-mvc, service, controller, repository, spring-data-jpa

The following code should delete some Order by using the orderID. I'm confused as to the parameters of the method as if this method relies on an orderID how would this work?

```
//code I am trying to replace

public String delete(@RequestParam(value="orderId", required=false, defaultValue="-1") int orderId, Model model) {
SomeApp.getStore().getOrderList().removeIf(p -> (p.getId() == orderId));
model.addAttribute("orderList", SomeApp.getStore().getOrderList());

//with this
public String orderDelete(Map<String, Object> model) {<--does this always stay this way?
    int orderID= OrderService.delete(orderId);
    orderRepository.delete(orderID)
    return "someform/orderMaster";
}
```

I have an order Entity, as well as an OrderRepo which extends CRUD.
Service business logic is in the Controller(above) and the Controller has an @Autowire for the OrderService.

Thanks(still getting used to SpringMVC/JPA Data so apologies for basic questions)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass which parameters do you need; Your method can be without parameters. Use N parameters do you need.

**Explication:**
1.`@RequestParam(value="orderId", required=false, defaultValue="-1") int orderId` - that will be a parameter in your requestUrl, example: `localhost:8080/deleteSomething?orderId=11`

2.`Model model` - this param is used to send in view orderList, that can be access in jsp as ${orderList}

You have to use that `Map<String, Object> model` in case if from view are passed some parameters, or do you need to pass parameter in view, in your case it's unnecessary .

```
//Autoware your service upper 

public String orderDelete(@RequestParam("orderId") int orderId) {
    orderService.deleteOrder(orderId)

    return "someform/orderMaster";
```

}

And yes, it's incorrect to delete your values firstly from service and after from repo. View how can you implements your repo + service  classes.

**Repo:**
    //create interface that will store all your operations

```
@Repository
public class OrderRepository implements OrderDAO {

//you may init it there or create a bean and autoware your session
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf) {
    this.sessionFactory = sf;
}

@Override
public void addOrder(Order order) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.persist(order);
}

@Override
public void updateOrder(Order order) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.update(event);
}

@Override
public void deleteOrder(int id) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Event e = (Event) session.load(Order.class, new Integer(id));
    if (null != e) {
        session.delete(e);
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
@Service
public class EventService {

@Autowired
private OrderDAO orderDAO;
//init somewhere bean orderDAO

   public void setOrderDAO(OrderDAO orderDAO) {
       this.orderDAO = orderDAO;
   }

   @Transactional
   public void addOrder(Order order) {
       orderDAO.addOrder(order);
   }

   @Transactional
   public void updateOrder(Order order) {
       orderDAO.updateOrder(order);
   }

   @Transactional
   public void deleteOrder(int id) {
       orderDAO.deleteOrder(id);
   }
}
```

Comment: My repo extends crudrepo<Order, Integer> and I haven't been taught to use sessions.

Comment: There is not session important, implements your repository how would you like. I show how you may correctly structure your code and don't invoke 2 methods when it is unnecessary.